# Do I need to update ios app if I change country availability?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have one app that I initially made available to just 2 countries.

Now I change it to all available countries and done save.

Will now the same app be available to all those countries, or I need to do update a new version ?

Comment: No you don't. BTW rather asking such question you should give a try on apple.com first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to update it. Just select the **countries** were you want it to be available and save the changes.

Comment: I need to wait 9 minutes to accept it. Do you have personal experience with this ? I was expecting another approval process from Apple, so this is very strange, but good.

Comment: Yes, last week I changed the availability of an app, from worldwide available, to all but one country, just need to save the changes on iTunes Connect. :)

Comment: I think it's since the new itunes connect that you can now changes some stuff without having to update a new version, like screenshots, keywords, etc...